# Get items, changed by current user, via JSOM

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, csom

In SharePoint 2013 JavaScript, I want to load all items from a list, that have been modified by the current user. I tried this:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var settings = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('My Setting List');

var settingQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
settingQuery.set_viewXml('<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Editor" LookupId="TRUE" /><Value Type="Integer"><UserID /></Value></Eq></Where></Query>');
var settingItems = settings.getItems(settingQuery);

ctx.load(settingItems, 'Include(Id, Title)');
ctx.executeQueryAsync( /* ... */ );
```

But it gives me all the items from all users. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SP.CamlQuery.viewXml Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee549968%28v=office.14%29.aspx) expects XML schema to be specified in the following format:

```
<View>
   <Query>
      ...
    </Query>
</View>
```

So, the solution is to enclose your query using `View` element.

**Example**

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var qry = new SP.CamlQuery();
qry.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Editor" LookupId="TRUE" /><Value Type="Integer"><UserID /></Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
var items = list.getItems(qry);

ctx.load(items, 'Include(Id, Title)');
ctx.executeQueryAsync( 
      function() {
         console.log(items.get_count());
      },
      function(sender,args){
         console.log(args.get_message());
      });
```

Comment: Damn, I forgot the View-Element, again! Thanks Vadim.